# Getting an internal job offer while on vacation, proper etiquette?

Tags: interviewing, internal-transfer

I am scheduled in a few weeks to have an interview with another department within my organization (internal position).  As per our company employee guidelines, it specifically states that one is to notify their supervisor or manager once they are applying for another position internally.  So at this point both my manager and the hiring manager of the other department are aware I will be interviewing.

A week and a half after I interview is when I will be taking an eight day vacation that was planned many months ago, with all plane tickets and hotels already paid for.  My question is, IF the other department makes the decision they want to hire me while I am on my vacation, what do you think would happen?  I would still be available to be contacted via phone and e-mail.  Should I just not take this vacation at all and lose the money, just so that I would be ready to transition at moments notice instead of waiting until I come back from vacation?  I have never applied for an internal job position before, always interviewed for completely different companies externally, so am unfamiliar with how these things go.

Any insights would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Consider asking your boss the questions that you have voiced. This seems pretty difficult to answer because we do not know your company policies or the relationships you have with your superiors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the new job is so vital to the success of the organization, that they have a absolutely-no-kidding-drop-dead-date that if the new person hasn't started by then everything will come crashing down, then your vacation days will not be an issue. If they need the person by a specific date they would let applicants know early in the process. One transfer I was a part of needed the new person in their seat by the end of the month, so that they would not be in violation of a government contract. We were very clear about this deadline.

For internal transfers your company doesn't want to make the former manager angry. They want to have time for turnover.  They still want to give the former manager time to adjust. They showed this by alerting your current manager that you applied. I have seen it done the opposite way, where the current manager isn't told until you accept, that way if you don't get the job you haven't damaged your relationship with your current manager.

While some parts of internal transfers are seamless: you don't need to sit through the benefits presentation; other parts still involve paperwork and take time. I worked for one place that wanted internals transfers to take place on the first day of a pay period. No exceptions.

All this means that as long as they can get in contact with you, and you can review documents, then you being on vacation should not be a problem. Make sure that you don't just use out-of-office  notifications, but that you also have as much forwarded to systems you can see while on vacation.

Answer (score 3):

At the end of your interview and you're talking about potential next steps, it might be an idea to bring up your vacation plans, in case they need to contact you again.

They'll then either contact you before you leave, or after you come back, or you'll come back to something in your inbox.

But as you've mentioned it, it's known and no one will be surprised that you're not immediately replying to emails/calls.

Answer (score 0):

You could let the hiring manager know you’re going on holiday and advise that you’re contactable in regards to being notified of the outcome or a quick call to discuss the next steps, but 8 days isn’t too long, I’m sure it shouldn’t be an issue.

I’ve moved internally before and there was still a lot of paper work to be processed and notice periods to be adhered to. I’d be very suprised if they expected you to transition at a moments notice.